# Why does Laravel saves each field as "true" when presenting the datas in an array?

Tags: php, laravel, orm

So, I have the following code:

```php
$homepage = Homepage::first();
if (!$homepage) {
  $homepage = new Homepage;
}

$homepage->first_presta_title = $request->first_presta_title;
$homepage->first_presta_content = $request->first_presta_content;
$homepage->second_presta_title = $request->second_presta_title;
$homepage->second_presta_content = $request->second_presta_content;
$homepage->third_presta_title = $request->third_presta_title;
$homepage->third_presta_content = $request->third_presta_content;
$homepage->shiatsu_text = $request->shiatsu_text;
$homepage->shiatsu_image = $request->shiatsu_image;
$homepage->doin_text = $request->doin_text;
$homepage->doin_image = $request->doin_image;

$homepage->save();
```

Everything works, but I wanted to see if there weren't any better way to save datas without asigning every single element to its column, then I found out someone answering to a question by using the following code:

```php
$homepage->save($request->all());
```

So I tried it by myself, but nothing happened: no error, but also nothing saved in my database.

So, is there any fastest way to save datas ? Is it possible to use a loop to save everything?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could we see your homepage model?

Comment: i never used that method, but MAYBE can be something related to the mass assignment (something similar to the `::create()` method), so you need to write your `$fillable` variable in the model, see here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: use createOrUpdate function it will make things much more easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `save()`, you are actually using [Mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment). So, either you explicitly define all the fields in your model to be mass assignable or you could use `create()` instead.

However, in your particular case, the whole method could be cleaned up to just one line:

```
return Homepage::updateOrCreate($request->all());
```

Comment: Holy molly, it worked like a charm, I hade to make a couple modifications to my Model, but i saves a lot of space, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you want the model to autofill based on a given array you need to create a new model entity Like this

```
 $homepage = HomePage::create($request->all());
 $homepage->save()
```

If you give an array to `save()` it expects the options for saving not for values to assign

Source:
[laravel api docs for model/save()](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_save)

[laravel api docs for model::create()](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_create)